# Named arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

Say I have a function like this

```
function myFunc(a, b, c)
{
    if(a!=undefined) this.a = a;
    if(b!=undefined) this.b = b;
    if(c!=undefined) this.c = c;
}
```

And I want to set only the value for b, then I could do something like this.

```
myFunc(undefined, "some Value for b", undefined);
```

But I was wondering if there was a way in which I could do something like this for setting the value of b

```
myFunc(b:"some value for b");
```

This is probably wrong, but you probably see what I mean. I want to specify the name of the property along with the value so that I do not have to worry about passing undefined values. How would I do this?

Also feel free to change the title, I have no idea what this question should be called.

Comment: This is a solution: http://ivanzuzak.info/2009/08/09/named-arguments-in-javascript.html

Comment: "I have no idea what this question should be called". Funniest stackoverflow moment of my life so far...

Comment: What's the intention with `this.a` etc? You're not instantiating an object, so `this` will be the global object.

Comment: @bfavaretto yes I am using this function for creating objects, even though not shown here

Comment: "_Do you mean to say that the example I gave actually works?_" Only if you change the syntax to use object literal notation (ie add `{}` around `b:"some value"`.  The key concept is that you're passing an Object as an argument.  Objects can be created using the _object literal_ notation, which looks like this: `{ propA: 'valueA', propB: 'valueB' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, pass in an object literal

```
function myFunc(options)
{
    if(options.a!=undefined) this.a = options.a;
    if(options.b!=undefined) this.b = options.b;
    if(options.c!=undefined) this.c = options.c;
}
```

and call like this

```
var var1 = new myFunc({b:"some value for b"});
```

or for a more dynamic, extensible way ( as mentioned)

```
function myFunc(obj)
{
    for (var i in obj)
    {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i))
        {
            this[i]=obj[i];
        }
    }
}

var func = new myFunc({b:"some value for b"});
console.log(func.b);//"some value for b"
```

Comment: note that if called like that, it will attach `b` to the window object.

Answer (score 4):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NLVD3/)

Sure, just use this:

```
function myFunc(options)
{
 if(typeof(options['a']) != "undefined") this.a = options['a'];
 if(typeof(options['b']) != "undefined") this.b = options['b'];
 if(typeof(options['c']) != "undefined") this.c = options['c'];
}
```

and then call it with

```
var func = new myFunc({b:"some value for b"});
console.log(func.b);//"some value for b"
```

Comment: @Ojay - You were correct, the options object needs to check for a string index and not a variable one.

Comment: @TravisJ I probably think that he meant that you are missing brackets

Comment: @AnkurSharma - Ah, the simple things. Fixed. ;)

Comment: @OJay I am wondering why obj[i] works and why not obj.i. Look here  -http://jsfiddle.net/GyBdz/ . Just trying to understand what is going on here.

Comment: @AnkurSharma in relation to your jsfiddle, works fine for me?; is your console open?

Comment: @OJay Yes but comment the first statement and uncomment the second statement. Then it logs undefined in console.

Comment: @AnkurSharma in the case of the for in loop, you are assigning the property name of the passed in object to the variable i. this[i] works because it replaces the i with the current property (i.e. b), so actually assigned this.b, whereas this.i is not using the variable i, you are actually creating a property of i on the function. try it, instead of console.log(func.b) with the second one, change it to console.log(func.i)

Comment: @Ojay Oh I see. Thanks for the wonderful explanation. I am going to sleep as one happy man tonight.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by passing an Ojbect as an argument:

```
var someObject = { a: 'some A value', b: 'some B value' };

myFunc(someObject);
```

This is a very common practice.

For example, jQuery uses this construct often.

If you look at the documentation for [jQuery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), you can see it accepts a [Plain Object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject) as the first argument.