# How to pass a function with named arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, argument-passing

I am creating an extension function:

```
 jQuery.fn.openCreatePersonModal = function (arg1, personHandler) {
        var person = { "displayName": "john" };
        personHandler(person);
        return this;
  }
```

But can't use it, neither this way:

```
$("<div></div>").openCreatePersonModal({
    arg1: "bla",
    personHandler: somePreviouslyCreatedFunction
});
```

Nor this way:

```
$("<div></div>").openCreatePersonModal({
    arg1: "bla",
    personHandler: function(person) { ... }
});
```

I'm getting:
undefined is not a function

So it is not recognizing somePreviouslyCreatedFunction as a function.

Comment: simple syntax error, you are expecting a function and passing an object. Pass `somePreviouslyCreatedFunction` or `new function(person) { ... }` directly, without the surrounding object (`{ personHandler: ... }`), and it will work.

Comment: Then accept (`function (personHandler, foo, bar) {`) and pass more parameters. If you want the named approach, then accept only one parameter and work with it, e.g: `function (args) { args.personHandler ...`.

Comment: Ahhh! THANKS. Post it as an answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Named arguments in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508282/named-arguments-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

If one wants to use named arguments, should use 1 argument and interpret it as an object

```
jQuery.fn.openCreatePersonModal = function (args) {
       var person = { "displayName": "john" };
       args.personHandler(person);                   // <-- notice "args."
       return this;
}
```